# android:singleton instance not garbage collected after application is closed

Tags: java, android, singleton, fragment

I have an android activity with a fragment.

In the fragment, I fetch data using retrofit and set a static flag, so that , when I again go to this fragment, I restrict fetching data again.

I also store the data in a singleton instance.

**But even after I destroyed the activity/closed the application, the static flag and the instance is still available and the list is also present in the instance, which malfunctions my app.**

**But I want the instance to be created newly and fetch data at each run.**

This is my singleton instance.

```
public class Utilities {

    private static Utilities utils = null;

    private List<Data> friendsList;

    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    private List<Data> dataList;

    public synchronized static Utilities getInstance(){

        if(utils == null){
            utils = new Utilities();
        }
        return utils;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment:

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static boolean hasObtainedData;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

        if(!hasObtainedData){
            getData(v);
        }else{
           recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(utils.getDataList()));
         }
     }

     private void getData(View v) {

         //get Data using Retrofit:
         hasObtainedData = true;
         utils.setDataList(dataListObtainedUsingRetrofit)
         recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(utils.getDataList()));
    } 
}
```

This is how, I call my fragment from MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragmentBox, new DataFragment()).commit();
    }
```

I tried giving System.gc() at onDestroy() of MainActivity, but still, the singleton instance is alive.

I search many SOF posts based on this, but wasn't able to solve this issue.

Any help will be really useful.

Comment: How about clearing your list in `onDestroy()` of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to the Singleton is static in the Utilities-Class itself, so the Singelton can never be available for GC, unless you set utils = null on leaving MainAcitivity with something like

```
Utilities.reset();
```

Comment: I tried this, but the boolean flag is still alive , how do I reset at the end of application!

Comment: remove static from the boolean

Comment: I fetch data once , and when I go to some other fragment and click this DataFragment, I dont want to fetch data again.So I kept the variable as static.How shall I do this without static ?

Comment: ok, then reset it on leaving, too; write a static DataFragment.reset(). Or even better, move the flag to the Utilities-Class into the Singleton

Comment: Ya, it is the only work around, but is it a good practice to use static variables in android, especially in my case of one time data retrieval?Am I writing the fragment code  in onTabSelected in a right way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android-Apps, I dont't know if or how you can make it local to your MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton wont survive your app being terminated, and what's probably happening is that you aren't actually killing the app entirely during your tests. Run `adb shell am force-stop <your-app-package>` from your console and see whether that still results in the issue.

With that said, if you only want your data to run once per application launch, then I would recommend you move it into the `onCreate()` lifecycle callback of your `Application`

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Begin process to fetch data and cache it here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the application name to your manifest too, `<application android:name="your.packagename.App"`

You then have no need to modify your data at all - it will only run once per application launch.

If, however, what you actually want is for your data to update every time the `Activity` is launched, then do the same process as before but inside `onCreate()` of you Activity. You can also clear it in `onDestroy()`, if you want it to updated when your Activity is recreated:

```
@Override
public void onDestry() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Utilities.getInstance().setDataList(null);
}
```

Also, if your data is bound to the lifecycle of your Activity, then you don't really need a singleton (which is bound to the lifecycle of the application).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PPartisan, I can't get your suggestion on Application class part!Yes I want to fetch data only once.But it is in the 3rd activity from app launch.How shall I use Application class for data fetching?

Comment: Begin the process to populate your data/singleton inside onCreate of your application.  This will only be called once per-Application launch, unlike your Activity lifecycle callbacks which may be called multiple times.

Comment: when will application lifecycle execute? even before all the activities?

Comment: Yes - the application is created before all activities.

Comment: If so, how shall I execute my retrofit data fetching in my Application class.Say, 1)If I  want to load my data lazily 2) Fetch data according to user input! in such a case, I may not be able to networking in my Application class right?Only static url data can be fetched ?

Comment: You can start a network request in your Application class just fine - use whatever process you would in your Activity. If you want to fetch data according to use input, then you can do that as well, but you wont be able to do that in your Application as you wont have access to user input